# Framer Motion: Animation Will not Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to loop an animation with the Framer Motion library after a small delay. The animation itself will play when it's mounted, on the webpage refresh, however does not repeat.
Iv'e looked through the docs and this seems to be similar syntax.

```
const AnimateTrial = {
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: -100,
    y: -35,
    scale: 0.9,
  },
  animate: (i) => {
    const delay = 5 + i * 0.5;
    return {
      opacity: 1,
      x: -10,
      y: -35,

      transition: {
        opacity: { delay, duration: 1.5 },
        x: { delay, duration: 1.5},
        repeatType: "Infinity",
        repeatDelay: 5,
      },
    };
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea? Everything works minus bottom two lines!

Comment: repeat: Infinity --- write without quotes, Infinity is js variable

Answer (score 6):

The properties inside your transition object are not right. Use `repeat` in place of `repeatType`, Write it something like this

**`transition={{ repeat: Infinity, repeatDelay: 5 }}`**

If you check the [docs](https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/###repeattype) repeateType property accepts only `"loop"`  `"reverse"` `"mirror"` and not `"Infinity"`.

Comment: Hi @Simran, unfortunately this isn't actually looping the animation. It's worth nothing the SVG is animated, not the DIV. I have the following object: 

`
const AnimateTrial = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.37,
      y:-10,
      x:-500,
    },
    animate: (i) => {
      const delay = 5 + i * 0.5;
      return {
        opacity: 1,
        scale: 0.37,
        y: -10,
        x: -255,
  
        transition: {
          repeat: Infinity,
          repeatDelay: 5,
        },
      };
    }
  };
`

Comment: In doc it shows that we can use Infinity `transition={{ repeat: Infinity, duration: 2 }}` link is [here](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###repeat)

Answer (score 1):

**Write without quotes**

The number of times to repeat the transition. Set to Infinity for perpetual repeating.
Without setting repeatType, this will loop the animation.

```
<motion.div
  animate={{ rotate: 180 }}
  transition={{ repeat: Infinity, duration: 2 }}
/>
```

link is [here](https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###repeat)

Answer (score 1):

```html
const AnimateTrial = {
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    x: -100,
    y: -35,
    scale: 0.9,
  },
  animate: (i) => {
    const delay = 5 + i * 0.5;
    return {
      opacity: 1,
      x: -10,
      y: -35,

      transition: {
        opacity: { delay, duration: 1.5 },
        x: { delay, duration: 1.5},
        repeat: Infinity, 
        repeatDelay: 5,
      },
    };
  }
```

use repeat instead of repeatType